# ¿Por que no agrega la información a la base de datos?

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php 
//conexion a la base de datos y el servidor
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","kenworth") or die("<h2>No se encuentra el servidor</h2>");;

//obtenemos los valores del formulario 
 $folio = $_POST['folio'];
 $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
 $entrega = $_POST['entrega'];
 $devolucion = $_POST['devolucion'];
 $concepto = $_POST['concepto'];
 $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
 $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
 $solicita = $_POST['solicita'];
 $autoriza = $_POST['autoriza'];

 //obtenemos la longitud de string
 $req = (strlen($folio)*strlen($nombre)*strlen($entrega)*strlen($devolucion)*strlen($concepto)*strlen($cantidad)*strlen($descripcion)*strlen($solicita)*strlen($autoriza)) or die("No se ha llenado los campos<br></br><a href='pres.html'>");

 //ingresamos la información a la base de datos
 mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO prestamos values ('$folio','$nombre','$entrega','$devolucion','$concepto','$cantidad','$descripcion','$solicita','$autoriza')");

?>


<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="es">    

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Solicitud de prestamos</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1maximum-scale=1user-scalable=no">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/materialize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/fakeLoader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spinnaker" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/fakeLoader.css">
</head>


<body style="background:#424242;">
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper" style="background-color:black;">
<img class="left" src="static/img/logo.png" width="325px">
  <ul id="nav-mobile" class=" right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="iniciodelapag.html">Inventario</a></li>
    <li><a href="Prestamos.html">Prestamos</a></li>
    <li><a href="InicioSesion.html">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<br>

<table border="1" class="black-text table table-bordered table-hover">
<h2 class="black-text">Prestamos de equipo</h2>

<tr>
   <td>Folio</td>   
   <td>Nombre</td>   
   <td>Entrega del prestamo</td>
   <td>Devolución del prestamo</td>
   <td>Concepto</td>
   <td>Cantidad</td>
   <td>Descripción del equipo</td>
   <td>Quien solicita</td>
   <td>Quien autoriza</td>
</tr>

<?php
   $sql="SELECT * from prestamos";
   $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);

   while ($mos=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   # code...

?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $mos['id']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Destino']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Fecha_Entrega']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['fecha_Devolucion']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Concepto']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Cantidad']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Descripcion']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Quien_solicita']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Quien_autoriza']?></td>
</tr>
<?php
 }
?>
</table> 
</body>
<style>
    button{
        background-color:#607d8b; 
        border-color: black;
    }
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #757575;
    }
  </style>



 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="reg.php"></script>
    <style type="text/css" src="Agregar.html" ></style>
    <script src="static/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/materialize-01.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').material_select();
     });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.datepicker').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear',
            close: 'Ok',
            closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
        });
</script>      

      </body>
</html>
```

Y el html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Solicitud de prestamos</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1maximum-scale=1user-scalable=no">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/materialize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/fakeLoader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spinnaker" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/fakeLoader.css">
</head>


<body style="background:#424242;">
  <div class="input-field col s12 center">
    <img src="static/img/logo.png" alt="" class="responsive-img" width="700px">
     <h2 class="black-text">Prestamos de equipo de cómputo</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <form action="Pres.php" method="POST" class="col s12">
  <div class="input-field col s1">
  <label>Folio</label>
  <input type="number" name="folio" id="folio"/>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s4">
    <label name="nombre" id="nombre" for="first_name" >Nombre/Destino</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="validate">
 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s4">
    <input type="text" name="entrega" id="entrega" class="datepicker">
    <label>Entrega de prestamo</label>
 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s3">
    <input type="text" name="devolucion" id="devolucion" class="datepicker">
    <label for="first_name">Devolución del prestamo</label>
</div>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s3">
<label name="concepto" position="center">Escribe un concepto</label>
 <input type="text" id="concepto" name="concepto" class="input-field col s12">
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="input-field col s6">
<label for="first_name" >Cantidad</label>
 <input name="cantidad" id="cantidad" type="number"> 
 </div>
 <div class="input-field col s6">
 <label for="Des">Descripción del equipo</label>
 <input name="descripcion" id="descripcion" type="text"> 
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s6">
<label>Quien solicita</label>
<input name="solicita" id="solicita" type="text">
</div>
<div class="input-field col s6">
<label>Quien autoriza</label>
<input name="autoriza" id="autoriza" type="text">
</div>     
</div>
<div class="row">
<a href="iniciodelapag.html"><input type="button" value="Regresar" style="background-color:#607d8b;"></a>
<input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="guardar" name="guardar" style="background-color:#607d8b;">
</div>
</form>
<style>
    button{
        width: 110%;
        background-color: black;
        border-color: black;
    }
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #757575;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/materialize-01.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="reg.php" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').material_select();
     });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('.datepicker').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear',
            close: 'Ok',
            closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
       });
</script>      
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#guardar').click(function(){
               var folio = document.getElementById("folio").value;
               var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
               var entrega = document.getElementById("entrega").value;
               var devolucion = document.getElementById("devolucion").value;
               var concepto = document.getElementById("concepto").value;
               var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
               var descripcion = document.getElementById("descripcion").value;
               var solicita = document.getElementById("solicita").value;
               var autoriza = document.getElementById("autoriza").value;
               //var detalles = document.getElementById("detalles").value;
               var i = 1;
               var fila = '<tr id="row'+ i + '"><td>' + folio + '</td><td>' + nombre + '</td><td>' + entrega + '</td><td>' + devolucion + '</td><td>' + concepto + '</td><td>' + cantidad + '</td><td>' + descripcion + '</td><td>' + solicita + '</td><td>'+ autoriza + '</td><td>'; 
           i++;

               $('#tabla tr:first').after(fila);
               var nfilas = $("#tabla tr").length;

               // document.getElementById("detalles").value= "";
               document.getElementById("autoriza").value = "";
               document.getElementById("solicita").value = "";
               document.getElementById("descripcion").value = "";
               document.getElementById("cantidad").value = "";
               document.getElementById("concepto").value = "";
               document.getElementById("devolucion").value = "";
               document.getElementById("entrega").value = "";
               document.getElementById("nombre").value = "";
               document.getElementById("folio").value = "";
               document.getElementById("folio").focus();        
          });
          $(document).on('click', 'btn_detalle', function(){
              var buton_id = $(this).attr("id");
              $('#row' + buton_id + '').
              document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
                  var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
              });
              $(document).ready(function(){
                   $('.modal').modal();
              });
          });
      });
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Julissa, en el diseño de tu tabla MySQL, cuáles son los tipos de los datos de cada columna, por ejemplo, folio es un ¿entero o un texto? Lo pregunto por que si tratas de guardar una cadena en un lugar donde se guardan enteros, lo más probable que te genere problemas al intentar guardar los registros.

Comment: El folio(id) lo tengo como entero, esos datos si están bien, pero no se por que no me agrega los datos

Comment: ¿Y el problema en sí cuál es? ¿Algún mensaje de error que nos puedas compartir? ¿Qué hace el código, qué debería hacer que no hace? Sin esto tendríamos que intentar adivinarlo todo.

Comment: A. Cedano, como tiene planteado el código Julissa no arroja errores, simplemente no hace nada. Envía los datos a procesar, pero cuando llega a la función mysqli_query() no hace nada, estoy seguro que el problema es el manejo de los tipos de datos, porque esta intentando ingresar una cadena de texto en un lugar que debería ser un entero.

Comment: @lepeman en ese caso tendría que evaluar el resultado de la consulta, por ejemplo: `if ( mysqli_query(....) ) {  //leer y mostrar datos } else { echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($link);}` Pues eso, controlar en todo momento el código y hacer que hable, que para eso se es programador ¿no? Lo que no se puede es escribir un código que en ciertos puntos haga lo que quiera y ni te enteras. Hay que prever cualquier error posible y saber qué hacer en esos casos.

Comment: A. Cedano, errar es humano... Tienes razón en lo que planteas, pero lo que ella está pidiendo es una mano para saber dónde podría estar el error y creo que ya se sabe cuál es.

Answer (score 0):

lamentablemente no sabemos cual es el diseño de tu base datos, pero nos cuentas que folio esta declarado como entero en MySQL, por lo tanto, primero debes castear y convertir $folio de Cadena a Entero (**$folio = (int)$_POST('folio')**) y en la linea de mysqli_query() debes quitarle las comillas a $folio.

Mi propuesta es esta:

```
<?php 
//conexion a la base de datos y el servidor
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","kenworth") or die("<h2>No se encuentra el servidor</h2>");;

//obtenemos los valores del formulario 
 $folio = (int)$_POST['folio'];
 $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
 $entrega = $_POST['entrega'];
 $devolucion = $_POST['devolucion'];
 $concepto = $_POST['concepto'];
 $cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
 $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
 $solicita = $_POST['solicita'];
 $autoriza = $_POST['autoriza'];

 //obtenemos la longitud de string
 $req = (strlen($folio)*strlen($nombre)*strlen($entrega)*strlen($devolucion)*strlen($concepto)*strlen($cantidad)*strlen($descripcion)*strlen($solicita)*strlen($autoriza)) or die("No se ha llenado los campos<br></br><a href='pres.html'>");

 //ingresamos la información a la base de datos
 mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO prestamos values ($folio,'$nombre','$entrega','$devolucion','$concepto','$cantidad','$descripcion','$solicita','$autoriza')");

?>


<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="es">    

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Solicitud de prestamos</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1maximum-scale=1user-scalable=no">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/materialize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/fakeLoader.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Spinnaker" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/fakeLoader.css">
</head>


<body style="background:#424242;">
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper" style="background-color:black;">
<img class="left" src="static/img/logo.png" width="325px">
  <ul id="nav-mobile" class=" right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="iniciodelapag.html">Inventario</a></li>
    <li><a href="Prestamos.html">Prestamos</a></li>
    <li><a href="InicioSesion.html">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<br>

<table border="1" class="black-text table table-bordered table-hover">
<h2 class="black-text">Prestamos de equipo</h2>

<tr>
   <td>Folio</td>   
   <td>Nombre</td>   
   <td>Entrega del prestamo</td>
   <td>Devolución del prestamo</td>
   <td>Concepto</td>
   <td>Cantidad</td>
   <td>Descripción del equipo</td>
   <td>Quien solicita</td>
   <td>Quien autoriza</td>
</tr>

<?php
   $sql="SELECT * from prestamos";
   $result=mysqli_query($link,$sql);

   while ($mos=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   # code...

?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $mos['id']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Destino']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Fecha_Entrega']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['fecha_Devolucion']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Concepto']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Cantidad']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Descripcion']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Quien_solicita']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $mos['Quien_autoriza']?></td>
</tr>
<?php
 }
?>
</table> 
</body>
<style>
    button{
        background-color:#607d8b; 
        border-color: black;
    }
    table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: scroll;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    td, th {
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #757575;
    }
  </style>



 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="reg.php"></script>
    <style type="text/css" src="Agregar.html" ></style>
    <script src="static/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/materialize-01.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('select').material_select();
     });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.datepicker').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
            selectYears: 15, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year,
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear',
            close: 'Ok',
            closeOnSelect: false // Close upon selecting a date,
        });
</script>      

      </body>
</html>
```